# How should this wall water damage be repaired?

Tags: drywall, walls, leak

I recently had a pipe burst in the apartment above me that caused some damage to my kitchen wall. My super came to repair. A few days after he was in my apartment to plaster the wall, it still seems like there is a problem, and seems to have a buildup of moisture.

My super is honestly not great at his job so I'd prefer he didn't come back... Is this something that requires more work, or do I need to wait it out a few days longer for it to dry? If it requires more work, is this something I can do on my own?

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

Comment: Doing a _good_ plaster job is an art form that can take many years of experience to perfect. Expecting a building super, who is a glorified handyman who has to handle _every_ situation in your building, to do an artist's job is unfair to both of you. If you want excellent results, hire someone who will provide them. You may need to have a conversation with the super about possibly splitting the cost in some way.

Comment: Whether you can do this repair is not a question for us. It depends on motivation, physical ability, etc. There are many [questions about drywall repairs](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+drywall+repair&rlz=1) on this site and elsewhere which can act as guides. If you like, please revise to ask _how_, not _whether_. Then we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks better in the after picture in any case.

Drywall or plaster repair is a many stage process.  Often you do 3 coats of mud with sanding in between before you get to priming and painting.  Stains can bleed through like you see but ultimately that doesn't matter as long as it doesn't bleed through the primer / paint.  You should expect 5 different appearances with time in between for drying/curing for a repair like this depending on if they use setting type compound or drying type compound.